# What is known about primorial and factorial minus one prime?

Tags: number-theory

$324$ is an example of an integer such that both $324!-1$ and $primorial(324)-1$ are primes.
Are there other examples?
Is there some condition to be $n! - 1$ and $primorial(n) -1$ both primes?

Comment: An integer being a square doesn't depend on what base it's written in; it's either the square of an integer or it's not.

Comment: The numbers of the form $n!\pm 1$ and $p$#$\pm1$ have been tested upto a high limit, but I do not know whether the combination you mention has been tested as well. Are you only interested in the combination $n!-1,n$#$-1$ ? If so, I can search for other examples.

Comment: There is no condition giving us a hint when $n!-1$ is prime and when $n$#$-1$ is prime, we have to test it.

Comment: @GregMartin I think, what the OP means , if we convert $324$ into base $16$ and read the result ($144$) as if it were a number in base $10$ , we get again a perfect square.

Comment: The first positive integers for which both $n!-1$ and $n$#$-1$ are prime are : $$[3, 4, 6, 12, 14, 94, 324]$$ I have not checked yet with the list of known examples , whether larger combinations exist.

Comment: The given sign-combination gives no other examples within the known primes of the form $n!-1$ , but the other $3$ combinations might give larger examples.

Comment: @Peter are those primes, or probable primes?

Comment: I rigorously checked the numbers in the examples giving a pair, they turned out to be actually prime.

Comment: I just noticed that all the known factorial and primorial primes should be proven primes because they can be proven to be prime with the $p-1$-test or the $p+1$-test.